# Only one apk from splited is uploaded to Google Play

Tags: android, gradle, triplet

Plugin uploads only apk with version 760XXX (where XXX - current version) but I have 5 different abis. All configs same as for default sample similar to this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
Maybe you can provide advice or idea how to check what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Does each apk has different version code, or the same one? They should be different. (the value is checked per ABI, so you can have version code 123 for arm7, and 5000 for mips, and apk with 124 for arm7 will be considered upgrade. For mips only 5001+ would work).

Answer (score 1):

From the page you linked:

> By default, when Gradle generates APK splits, each APK will have the same version information, as specified in the module-level build.gradle file. Because the Google Play Store does not allow multiple APKs for the same app that all have the same version information, you need to ensure each split APK has its own unique versionCode before you upload to the Play Store.

If you have already different version codes, then this answer is useless for you (still first thing to check for anyone encountering the similar problem).